# How to lookup value from sheet1 on sheet2, and then fill in the date to the right of match on sheet2

Tags: google-apps-script

Complete Google Apps Script novice question.  I am trying to build some additional functionality into my spreadsheet where I can attach a script to a button that "checks off" the current selection as completed with the current date on a different sheet.

The pages are on one page of the sheet "sheet1" and the index of all pages are on "sheet2".

I am trying to run a textfind/replace function to find the cell of the match from sheet1, match  the cell value from a column in "sheet2".  From there I was thinking to try and pull out the row and column of that cell and then try write the date one cell to the right.

Im not sure how to pull the row and column out of the .getA1notation() below... and then really not sure if this is the right way to approach the problem.

From below I would want to look up the cell values from sheet 2 (F1143 on this one) and then write the current date in G1143.

Here is where I am so far:

```
function markComplete() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var encounterSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var tosearch = "chapter1"; //hoping to make cell reference from "sheet1"
  var tf = encounterSheet.createTextFinder(tosearch);
  var all = tf.findAll();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('The sheet %s, cell %s, has the value %s.', all[i].getSheet().getName(), all[i].getA1Notation(), all[i].getValue());
    Logger.log(all[i].getA1Notation());
  }

}
```

```
Logger results:
8:41:33 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:41:34 AM  Info    The sheet Sheet2, cell F1143, has the value Chapter1.
8:41:34 AM  Info    F1143
8:41:34 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Sheet.findAll() returns an array of the ranges containing that text.

```
let all = tf.findAll();
all.forEach( range => range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
```

Reference

- [TextFinder.findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findAll())
- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))

Comment: I was making this much more difficult than it actually was. thanks for the quick response.  This worked perfectly!